# How can I get as much data as possible off a phone with broken USB?

Tags: backup, data-recovery

I have a BV7000pro running Marshmallow (according to the specs - it's off now for a good reason that will become clear soon).  It stopped charging after a period of very poor battery life, so I bought a replacement battery.  It still doesn't charge, doesn't show a charging LED and, despite having previously enabled developer mode, and checked just now, it doesn't show up when I run `adb devices` from the terminal.  It does turn on, but I only have about 70% of one charge, which is why I'm keeping the battery disconnected for the time being.

Although it's only my spare handset, I have data I'd like to get off before it's completely dead.  I can put in an SD card, and it's on WiFi.  I think it's mainly app data, though there are some photos (most were on an SD card but the stock  camera app sometimes switched to internal storage).

Google's backup appears to only be any use to restore to the same phone, so that's not much use, though it's present in my GDrive. (If I can download this an extract stuff from it I'd be interested to hear, but that's not the focus of the question).  *Edit: I was apparently wrong and it could restore to a newer phone - but I don't have one I can overwrite; my newer phone is my main phone*

BTW I'm also considering buying a replacement USB board on AliExpress, but I'm not sure if it's just a case of throwing good money after bad given that it's a battered old backup phone. It's no longer waterproof after falling off my bike too many times, which also led to me replacing the screen myself. At least it's easy to work on.

So, with no USB connection and one charge in the battery, how can I extract as much data as possible from my handset?  It's not rooted,and I already have one or two file manager apps on there (at least the free version of file commander).

Comment: Please do not use comments to extend your question. You can edit your question at any time and add more information. I did this for you this time...

Comment: Google Drive backup should be restorable as long as the device to restore to has the same or a higher Android version. As far as I remember GDrive backup on Android 6 was limited to apps and their app-data that explicitly requested it and it is limited to 5, 15 or 25 MB per app (not sure which value is effective in your case). In any way I would try to start copying all files you can reach via USB to a PC.

Comment: @Robert I felt the comment was background rather than adding anything to the question.  I'll delete it (on second thoughts, I left it in the Q, but in the middle)

Comment: @Robert on the more technical comments: I'd expect restoring a backup to a newer phone to overwrite what's on that phone - not an option as the only other phone I have is my main device.  And you suggest copying what I can via USB, but the whole point of the question is that USB is broken.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part because you only mention it in the title. Please do misuse the title for providing important info A title is there for summarizing the questions, it is not the first line of the questions. With a  broken USB you can still use one of the file-explorer or FTP/HTTP server apps that can provide the `/sdcard` section via FTP or HTTP. So effectively you can get all the files you would have access to via USB. See for example this FTP server app: https://f-droid.org/en/packages/be.ppareit.swiftp_free/

Comment: @Robert it wasn't only in the title - the last paragraph starts, and started, "So, with no USB connection and one charge in the battery..."

Comment: ...but that looks like it might be a good answer - thoguh I don't know if it offers as much as `adb backup`

Comment: For `adb backup` you require a wireless adb connection which usually requires an USB connection to activate the adb Wfif connection. If you manage to get adb to work over Wifi without USB connection you should backup all apps via adb just to be sure.

Comment: @Robert yes, I'm used to running adb over loopback (faked as WiFi) to allow Tasker to control aeroplane mode on my new phone; I'd assumed that adb backup was impossible without USB, but also think that it can grab more than copying files